# finding x y cordinates of an image visible on panel

Tags: c#, desktop-application

Currently, I'm using a panel to display image. I have already implemented a logic to zoom and move image via mouse.
My question is,when i zoom or move image , i want to crop and save only the part of an image that is visible on the panel.

here is the code i used to zoom & move image,

```
    namespace ImageZooming
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public class overRidePanel : Panel
        {
            protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent) { }
        }
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext;
        BufferedGraphics myBuffer;
        PointF viewPortCenter;
        float Zoom = 1.0f;
        string sFilePath;
        bool draging = false;
        Point lastMouse;
        int cropX;
        int cropY;
        byte[] MyData = new byte[0];
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.panel1.MouseWheel += new MouseEventHandler(panel1_MouseWheel);
            currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
            setup(false);
        }
        private void setup(bool resetViewport)
        {
            if (myBuffer != null)
                myBuffer.Dispose();
            myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(this.panel1.CreateGraphics(), this.panel1.DisplayRectangle);
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                if (resetViewport)
                    SetViewPort(new RectangleF(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
            }
            this.panel1.Focus();
            this.panel1.Invalidate();
        }
        private void SetViewPort(RectangleF worldCords)
        {
            //Find smallest screen extent and zoom to that
            if (worldCords.Height > worldCords.Width)
            {
                //Use With as limiting factor
                this.Zoom = worldCords.Width / bitmap.Width;
            }
            else
                this.Zoom = worldCords.Height / bitmap.Height;

            viewPortCenter = new PointF(worldCords.X + (worldCords.Width / 2.0f), worldCords.Y + (worldCords.Height / 2.0f));
            //  this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Zoom: " + ((int)(this.Zoom * 100)).ToString() + "%";

        }
        private void SetViewPort(Rectangle screenCords)
        {
        }
        private void PaintImage()
        {
            if (bitmap != null)
            {
                float widthZoomed = panel1.Width / Zoom;
                float heigthZoomed = panel1.Height / Zoom;

                //Do checks the reason 30,000 is used is because much over this will cause DrawImage to crash
                if (widthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel1.Width / 30000.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed > 30000.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel1.Height / 30000.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 30000.0f;
                }

                //we stop at 2 because at this point you have almost zoomed into a single pixel
                if (widthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel1.Width / 2.0f;
                    widthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }
                if (heigthZoomed < 2.0f)
                {
                    Zoom = panel1.Height / 2.0f;
                    heigthZoomed = 2.0f;
                }

                float wz2 = widthZoomed / 2.0f;
                float hz2 = heigthZoomed / 2.0f;
                Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.X - wz2),
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.Y - hz2),
                    (int)(widthZoomed),
                    (int)(heigthZoomed));

                //this.toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "DrawRect = " + drawRect.ToString();

                myBuffer.Graphics.Clear(Color.White); //Clear the Back buffer

                //Draw the image, Write image to back buffer, and render back buffer
                myBuffer.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, this.panel1.DisplayRectangle, drawRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                myBuffer.Render(this.panel1.CreateGraphics());
                // this.label1.Text = "Zoom: " + ((int)(this.Zoom * 100)).ToString() + "%";   //to show zooming %
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setup(false);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fdg = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (fdg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                bitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(fdg.FileName);
                setup(true);
            }
            sFilePath = fdg.FileName;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                draging = true;
        }
       // public Pen cropPen;
        private void panel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //cropPen=new Pen(Color.Black,1);
            //cropX = e.X;
            //cropY = e.Y;
            if (draging)
            {

                viewPortCenter = new PointF(viewPortCenter.X + ((lastMouse.X - e.X) / Zoom), viewPortCenter.Y + ((lastMouse.Y - e.Y) / Zoom));
                panel1.Invalidate();
            }
            //panel1.CreateGraphics().DrawRectangle(cropPen, 0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height);
            lastMouse = e.Location;
        }

        private void panel1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                draging = false;
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            PaintImage();
        }

        private void panel1_MouseWheel(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Zoom += Zoom * (e.Delta / 1200.0f); 
            if (e.Delta > 0 && e.Delta < 0) 
                viewPortCenter = new PointF(viewPortCenter.X + ((e.X - (panel1.Width / 2)) / (2 * Zoom)), viewPortCenter.Y + ((e.Y - (panel1.Height / 2)) / (2 * Zoom)));
            this.panel1.Invalidate();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of the image which is visible in the panel is already written in the above code: that is

```
Rectangle drawRect = new Rectangle(
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.X - wz2),
                    (int)(viewPortCenter.Y - hz2),
                    (int)(widthZoomed),
                    (int)(heigthZoomed));
```

from the above code you can find the X and Y coordinates of the drawRect and its width and height.

```
  X=drawRect.X;
  Y=drawRect.Y;
  width=widthZoomed;
  height=heightZoomed;
```